# Application shows this warning (This app isn't verified)

Tags: java, playframework

I have developed an web application using google app engine.

Application shows this warning screen (This app isn't verified) when I try to connect with Google OAuth.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJdVE.png)

Please note that I have already submit this form : https://support.google.com/...

and I have follow this steps : https://support.google.com/...

i want to resolve this warning

Comment: Both the "form" and "steps" links you've posted are just to support.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

Can't view the two links (assuming they're pointing to the conversations). From the screenshot seems like the app registered with Google to use the auth token and key needs to be validated first (I know this sounds obvious...). If the 'app' is not yet live then still you might need to first use sandbox details to develop it.